# some doubts in the following code

Tags: visual-c++

have a look at the code below once and help me out by clarifying my doubts. 
I have commented my doubts on each lines where i  have doubts. Moreover, its a part of code from a huge one. so please ignore the variable declarations and all.

The whole code is working perfect and no errors while compiled.

```
double Graph::Dijkstra( path_t& path )
{
    int* paths = new int[_size];
    double min = dijkstra(paths); // **is a function call or not? bcz i didn't found any function in the code**
   if(min < 0) { delete[] paths; return -1;}


    int i = _size - 1;  
    while(i>=0)
    {       
        path.push(i);   // **when will the program come out of this while loop, i'm wondering how does it breaks?** 
        i=paths[i];         
    }

    path.push(0); 

    delete[] paths;
    return min;
}
```

Full coding is available [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads155/sourcecode/others/689480/ksp/Graph.cpp__.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 double min = dijkstra(paths); // **is a function call or not? bcz i didn't found any function in the code**
```

It almost certainly is. However, it could be a free function, member function, function invoked by a macro, or something else. Without seeing the rest of the code, we can only guess.

```
while(i>=0)
{       
    path.push(i);   // **when will the program come out of this while loop, i'm wondering how does it breaks?** 
    i=paths[i];         
}
```

The program will come out of the loop as a soon as `i` is less than zero. If I had to guess, I'd say the each node in the path contains a link to the previous node's index with the last node in a path returning `-1` or some other negative number.

Comment: thanks. How does a function invoked by a macro? can u just give a example of how it would be.
here is the full code. if you can clear what it is, it would be great.
http://read.pudn.com/downloads155/sourcecode/others/689480/ksp/Graph.cpp__.htm

Comment: @NRK: Say you have `#define foo(x) (bar(x)->baz())` somewhere. Now somewhere else, you see `foo(2)`. So you decide to search for a function called `foo`, but there is no function called `foo` -- other functions, `bar` and `baz` are invoked by a macro.

Comment: aha thats clear about the macro now. thanks for ur help.
Then it doesn't seem like macro invokation here in my problem. 
can you have a look at it, if you had some time.

Comment: It's a function call. The function it's calling starts at line 305.

Comment: But, the function in line 305 has 3 parameters and the above has only one parameter right. is it possible so ?

Comment: Look in the header file. You'll see either that function or the one on line 371 has default values so those parameters can be omitted.

Comment: even i had one last doubt about the namespace Mido::utility.
what  does it suggest? why it needed so?

Comment: I have no idea. Remove it and see if it still compiles.

Comment: What errors? That will tell you why it's needed. (Or search the header files for `Mido`.)

Comment: it shown a lot... if u want to have a look at them, i'll show you.

Comment: the header file is [here]
(http://read.pudn.com/downloads155/sourcecode/others/689480/ksp/Graph.h__.htm)

Comment: The header puts the `Graph` class inside the namespace `Mido::utility`. Without that `using` declaration, you'd have to say `Mido::utility::Graph` instead of `Graph`.

Comment: ok. since graph class in inside that we have to do so. But, i compiled by changing in the header file too and still errors found.